# how can change raw color in html table using powershell?

Tags: html, css, powershell, date

ı want to colored specific raw. if licence days > 90 ,color red. other stiuation yellow or green. how can do that?  My table turn report html table.

```
    $sInFile = "C:\Users\akilic\Desktop\tarihlerr.csv"
    $cInCsv = Import-Csv -Path $sInFile -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF7
    $StartDate = Get-Date 
    $sDateFormat = "%d.%m.%Y"
    
    $header = @"
    <style>
    table {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
    th {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;}
    td {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
  
    }
    
    </style>
    "@
    
           
    $result = foreach ($ThisUser in $cInCsv) {  
        
        $EndDate = Get-Date ($ThisUser.'bitis')
        $licence = (New-TimeSpan –Start $StartDate  –End $EndDate).Days
        $ThisUser | Select-Object product,bitis, @{Name='gun'; Expression={$licence}}
           
        if($licence -lt 90 -and $licence -gt 0) {
            # output the selected object to be collected in variable $result
            $ThisUser | Select-Object product,bitis, @{Name='gun'; Expression={$licence}} 
               
        }
        elseif ($licence -lt 0){
            $pos = [Math]::Abs($licence) 
            $ThisUser | Select-Object product,bitis,@{Name='gun'; Expression={$licence}}
        }
    }
    $result | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header | Out-File "C:\Users\akilic\Desktop\health.html"
```

Comment: As aside: I see you are using the code I gave in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72491945/9898643). May I ask you to have a little peek at the [tour] to find out how you can make a question 'done'?

Comment: For what you want to do, you need to manipulate the html afterwards. Perhaps [this](https://petri.com/adding-style-powershell-html-reports/) may help there.

Comment: ı want to change color just specific coloumn "$licence".

Comment: Yes, it is clear what you want to do, but as said, `ConvertTo-Html` is a nice cmdlet, but it can only handle one style for the whole table. To color individual rows, columns or cells you need to manipulate the rendered HTML afterwards and either insert inline style on those cells or insert class attributes onto these. I didn't test this, but here's a function that you might try: [Color a single cell](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1931401-color-a-single-cell)

Comment: can you give me an example pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in this case you can manipulate the HTML like below:

Change your `$header` variaable into this to add three class definitions:

```
$header = @"
<style>
table {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
th {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;}
td {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
.redgun    {background-color: #ff0000; text-align: right;}
.yellowgun {background-color: #ffcc00; text-align: right;}
.greengun  {background-color: #33cc00; text-align: right;}
}
</style>
"@
```

Then change the final line of the code into:

```
$html = switch -Regex ($result | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header) {
    '<td>(-?\d+)</td></tr>$' {
        $gunValue = [int][regex]::Match($_,'(?i)<td>(-?\d+)</td></tr>$').Groups[1].Value
        if ($gunValue -gt 90) { $cell = '<td class="redgun">' }        # red
        elseif ($gunValue -lt 0) { $cell = '<td class="yellowgun">' }  # yellow
        else { $cell = '<td class="greengun">' }                       # green
        # replace that part of the string to insert the class
        $_ -replace '<td>-?\d+</td></tr>$', ('{0}{1}</td></tr>' -f $cell, $gunValue)
    }
    default { $_ }
}

$html | Out-File "C:\Users\akilic\Desktop\health.html"
```

Output:

[image]

---

If you don't want the single cell to have a different background color, but instead color the whole row, do this:

```
$header = @"
<style>
table {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
th {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;}
td {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
.redgun    {background-color: #ff0000;}
.yellowgun {background-color: #ffcc00;}
.greengun  {background-color: #33cc00;}
}
</style>
"@

$html = switch -Regex ($result | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header) {
    '<td>(-?\d+)</td></tr>$' {
        $gunValue = [int][regex]::Match($_,'(?i)<td>(-?\d+)</td></tr>$').Groups[1].Value
        if ($gunValue -gt 90) { $row = '<tr class="redgun">' }        # red
        elseif ($gunValue -lt 0) { $row = '<tr class="yellowgun">' }  # yellow
        else { $row = '<tr class="greengun">' }                       # green
        # replace the string to insert the class
        $_ -replace '^<tr>', $row
    }
    default { $_ }
}

$html | Out-File "C:\Users\akilic\Desktop\health.html"
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This output that I get.

I need change color "gun" column or all raw.

[image]